# How to get build time stamp from Jenkins build variables?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

How can I get build time stamp of the latest build from Jenkins?
I want to insert this value in the Email subject in post build actions.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**NOTE:** This changed in Jenkins 1.597, Please see [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JENKINS-24380+Migration) for more info regarding the migration

You should be able to view all the global environment variables that are available during the build by navigating to `https://<your-jenkins>/env-vars.html`.

Replace `https://<your-jenkins>/` with the URL you use to get to Jenkins webpage (for example, it could be `http://localhost:8080/env-vars.html`).

One of the environment variables is :

```
BUILD_ID
    The current build id, such as "2005-08-22_23-59-59" (YYYY-MM-DD_hh-mm-ss)
```

If you use jenkins editable email notification, you should be able to use `${ENV, var="BUILD_ID"}` in the subject line of your email.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I used: $BUILD_ID and zentimestamp plugin to change the format.

Comment: as of Jenkins v.1.597 this technique does not work https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JENKINS-24380+Migration

Comment: @OK. it doesn't actually work as before. It now contains the build number. From `env-vars.html`: " _**BUILD_ID**
The current build ID, identical to BUILD_NUMBER for builds created in 1.597+, but a YYYY-MM-DD_hh-mm-ss timestamp for older builds_".

Comment: @FrontierPsycho: That's interesting, where did you get this `env-vars.html` output from? Mine still states YYYY-MM-DD_hh-mm-ss format (in German, Jenkins version 2.7). There seems to be some confusion about env-vars and their documentation anyway...

Comment: @OK.: if jenkins-server.com is your jenkins server's domain, you can find it at http://jenkins-server.com/env-vars.html . My quote is straight from my Jenkins server, which is version 1.638.

Comment: @FrontierPsycho: Thanks for the clarification. I was able to access the page, but due to my browsers setting of German as default language, Jenkins served me a translated page. Seems like the translation of the `env-vars.html` page is out of date. If I set the browsers default to English, I get the same output as you.

Answer (score 40):

**Build Timestamp Plugin** will be the Best Answer to get the `TIMESTAMPS` in the Build process.

Follow the below Simple steps to get the `"BUILD_TIMESTAMP"` variable enabled.

**STEP 1:**

```
Manage Jenkins > Plugin Manager > Available plugins (or Installed plugins)...
Search for "Build Timestamp".
Install with or without Restart.
```

**STEP 2:**

```
Manage Jenkins > Configure System.
Search for 'Build Timestamp' section, then Enable the CHECKBOX.
Select the TIMEZONE, TIME format you want to setup with..Save the Page.
```

**USAGE:**

```
When Configuring the Build with ANT or MAVEN, 
Please declare a Global variable as, 
E.G.  btime=${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}
(use this in your Properties box in ANT or MAVEN Build Section)

use 'btime' in your Code to any String Variables etc..
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. I'm using this BUILD_TIMESTAMP variable. But my job runs on multiple slave machines  (nodes). As a result, I'm getting different build time for different Nodes.  Any way I can get a common time for all the Nodes running in the same job. Thanks

Comment: This is great. Should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 16):

One way this can be done is using shell script in global environment section, here, I am using UNIX timestamp but you can use any shell script syntax compatible time format:

```
pipeline {

    agent any

    environment {
        def BUILDVERSION = sh(script: "echo `date +%s`", returnStdout: true).trim()
    }

    stages {
        stage("Awesome Stage") {
            steps {
                echo "Current build version :: $BUILDVERSION"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try use `Build Timestamp Plugin` and use `BUILD_TIMESTAMP` variable.

Answer (score 5):

Generate environment variables from script (Unix script) :

```
echo "BUILD_DATE=$(date +%F-%T)"
```

Answer (score 2):

I know its late replying to this question, but I have recently found a better solution to this problem without installing any plugin. We can create a formatted version number and can then use the variable created to display the build date/time. 
Steps to create: Build Environment --> Create a formatted version number:

- Environment Variable Name: **BUILD_DATE**
- Version Number Format String: **${BUILD_DATE_FORMATTED}**

thats it. Just use the variable created above in the email subject line as         **${ENV, var="BUILD_DATE"}** and you will get the date/time of the current build.

Comment: This requires the "Version Number" plugin

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Jenkins object to fetch the start time directly

```
Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(<your_job_name>).getBuildByNumber(<your_build_number>).getTime()
```

also answered it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63074829/1968948

Answer (score 1):

`BUILD_ID` used to provide this information but they changed it to provide the Build Number since Jenkins 1.597. Refer [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JENKINS-24380+Migration) for more information.

You can achieve this using the [Build Time Stamp](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-timestamp) plugin as pointed out in the other answers.

However, if you are not allowed or not willing to use a plugin, follow the below method:

```
def BUILD_TIMESTAMP = null
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'JenkinsCredentials', passwordVariable: 'JENKINS_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'JENKINS_USERNAME')]) {
   sh(script: "curl https://${JENKINS_USERNAME}:${JENKINS_PASSWORD}@<JENKINS_URL>/job/<JOB_NAME>/lastBuild/buildTimestamp", returnStdout: true).trim();
}
println BUILD_TIMESTAMP
```

This might seem a bit of overkill but manages to get the job done.

The credentials for accessing your Jenkins should be added and the id needs to be passed in the `withCredentials` statement, in place of `'JenkinsCredentials'`. Feel free to omit that step if your Jenkins doesn't use authentication.

Answer (score 0):

This answer below shows another method using "regexp feature of the Description Setter Plugin" which solved my problem as I could not install new plugins on Jenkins due to permission issues:

[Use build timestamp in setting build description Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34676904/use-build-timestamp-in-setting-build-description-jenkins?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

If you want add a timestamp to every request from browser to jenkins server.
You can refer to the jenkins crumb issuer mechanism, and you can hack the /scripts/hudson-behavior.js  add modify here. so it will transform a timestamp to server.

```
    /**
     * Puts a hidden input field to the form so that the form submission will have the crumb value
     */
    appendToForm : function(form) {
        // add here. ..... you code
        if(this.fieldName==null)    return; // noop
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = "<input type=hidden name='"+this.fieldName+"' value='"+this.value+"'>";
        form.appendChild(div);
    }
```