# Use build timestamp in setting build description Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have installed Description Setter Plugin but I don't know if and how I can use the BUILD_ID which in jenkins/env-vars.html/ is displayed in the format: "2005-08-22_23-59-59" (YYYY-MM-DD_hh-mm-ss).
Does anyone know if I can use it and how?

Displaying the BUILD_ID would be the easiest way to add timestamp to the build description, but if not possible, how can I achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They replaced the `${BUILD_ID}` variable to contain the build number instead of this timestamp (since 1.597+). See https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26520

There are some workarounds with other plugins like EnvInject or you just use the regexp feature of the Description Setter Plugin like this:

- add execute shell blog (works for Linux)
- insert command `echo "date:" $(date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')`
- Set Description Setter plugin to regexp `date:(.*)`
- Set Description Setter plugin to description `\1`

Comment: yes, it works like that, just instead shell I used batch command for Windows: @echo off
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (`wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE 2^>NUL`) do if '.%%i.'=='.LocalDateTime.' set ldt=%%j
set ldt=%ldt:~0,4%-%ldt:~4,2%-%ldt:~6,2% %ldt:~8,2%:%ldt:~10,2%:%ldt:~12,6%
echo date: [%ldt%]

Answer (score 4):

If you have a fresh Jenkins version (1.6xx), you have to install the [ZenTimestamp plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ZenTimestamp+Plugin) and use the BUILD_TIMESTAMP variable:

[image]

[image]

You can customise the format in the global Jenkins settings:

[image]

(my solution also shows how to use a custom link as a description)

Comment: Which Jenkins version are you using? I tested with 1.643 and the variabloe $BUILD_ID contains the build number not a date anymore.

Comment: yes, I have 1.602 and for me also it displays the build number instead of date...:(

Comment: I did my test with an old version, I'll update my post with a new solution :)

Comment: Build Timestamp Plugin looks a little fresher and more featured than Zen Timestamp Plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Timestamp+Plugin

Answer (score 2):

"[Build Timestamp Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Timestamp+Plugin)"  will be the Best Answer to get the TIMESTAMPS in the Build process. Follow the below Simple steps to get the "BUILD_TIMESTAMP" variable enabled.

STEP1:

```
    Manage Jenkins -> Plugin Manager -> Installed...
    Search for "Build Timestamp Plugin".
    Install with or without Restart.
```

STEP2:

```
    Manage Jenkins -> Configure System.
    Search for 'Build Timestamp' section, then Enable the CHECKBOX.
    Select the TIMEZONE, TIME format you want to setup with..Save the Page.
```

USAGE:

```
    When Configuring the Build with ANT or MAVEN, 
    Please declare a Global variable as, 
    E.G.  btime=${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}
    (use this in your Properties box in ANT or MAVEN Build Section)

    use 'btime' in your Code to any String Variables etc..
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [groovy token](https://plugins.jenkins.io/groovy/#plugin-content-token-macro-plugin-support) such as:

```
${GROOVY,script = "String.format('%tF %<tH:%<tM', java.time.LocalDateTime.now())"}
```

It will add to the build description timestamp like: 2021-12-05 13:29

Note that [build.getTimestampString2()](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html#getTimestampString2--) would also print the timestamp, but **according to UTC** (in my timezone it's two hours earlier): 2021-12-05T11:29:09Z