# Getting Jenkins build time when started

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-plugins

I want to get the time when a build was started. I know the build name and number, but trick is the build may not have completed yet. The script can run on the Jenkins server or can be an API call. Any way I can accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

You can install [ZenTimestamp Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/ZenTimestamp+Plugin) and get the time stamp using `BUILD_TIMESTAMP` variable added by this plugin.

**Note:**

1. You need to specify SimpleDateFormat pattern (e.g. `yyyyMMddHHmmss`).
2. You must activate the Global Property!

Answer (score 0):

Under the Jenkins job you will find Polling Log on the left hand side
or you can just use the url like so 
jenkinsurl/job/jobName/buildNumber/pollingLog/pollingLog

All the details will be available here and you can find the time it started, by who,which revision ip address...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the Jenkins object to get the start time. For this inside your script.

```
Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(<your_job_name>).getBuildByNumber(<your_build_number>).getTime()
```

Answer (score 0):

For local time, try:

```
java.time.LocalDateTime.now()
```

For UTC try:

```
build.getTimestampString2()
```