# How do I get a list of all macros in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, macros

How do I access the current date as a macro in Jenkins?

[image]

> Caused by: org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.MacroEvaluationException: Unrecognized macro 'BUILD_TIMESTAMP' in 'sprint5-${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}'

`${DATE}` didn't work either. Nothing in the glossary about `macro`. https://jenkins.io/doc/book/glossary/

No useful search results. https://duckduckgo.com/?q=jenkins+date+macro&ia=web

Comment: The title is about all macros, but the question only asks for build timestamp. Please clarify, for future searches.

Comment: @handras If I find a list of all macros I can search for the date macro. (Or find there is no such thing.) Also I may want to use a different macro later. It would be a good reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check all default environment variables on `http://<JENKINS_IP>:<JENKINS_PORT>/env-vars.html` or from official [page](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-belowJenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables).
By default there is no time environment variable. Previously it could be possible to use `${BUILD_ID}`, but now it is identical to `${BUILD_NUMBER}` for builds created in 1.597+ Jenkins.

For using `${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}` environment variable in your job, you need to install (and [configure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44011594/10721592)) [Build Timestamp Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Timestamp+Plugin).

Note: I cannot check if you can use that plugin in `Version Label Format` step exactly, so probably you can also look at [Zentimestamp Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Zentimestamp+Plugin).

Answer (score 3):

You find all available environment variables here, on [Jenkins wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-belowJenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables).
Other plugins may define additional macros.

Comment: Due to SEO of the title of this question, this was actually the answer I needed despite the content of the OP question. Thank you!